# How to display names after regexp?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find all files in a directory that match 'hello'. i have the following code:

```
fileData = dir();   
m_file_idx = 1;
fileNames = {fileData.name};  
index = regexp(filenames,'\w*hello\w*','match') ;
inFiles = fileNames(~cellfun(@isempty,index));
```

Ex. if my directory has 3 files with the word hello in it, inFiles returns me

```
inFiles = 

    [1x23 char]    [1x26 char]    [1x25 char]
```

instead i want inFiles to return me the name of the file,ex thisishello.m,hiandhello.txt
how can i do this in a simple way?

Comment: Sounds like `inFiles` is a cell array, which you can index using {}, e.g. `inFiles{1}`. I'd suggest learning a little more about the very basics of matlab in the help manual or a tutorial, such as [this](http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/dataStructures.html#13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
fileData = dir();
fileNames = {fileData.name};

disp('The full directory...')
disp(fileNames)

index = regexp(fileNames,'\w*hello\w*','match');
inFiles = fileNames(~cellfun(@isempty,index));

disp('Print out the file names')
inFiles{:}
```

generates this output:

```
>> script
The full directory...
  Columns 1 through 6

    '.'    '..'    'andsevenyears.txt'    'fourscore.txt'    'hello1.txt'    'hello2.txt'

  Column 7

    'script.m'

Print out the file names

ans =

hello1.txt


ans =

hello2.txt
```

To me it looks as if you were having some issues with understanding cell arrays.  [Here's a specific tutorial that works through the](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Cell_Arrays)m.  (jerad's link also looks like a good resource)

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on here is that when an element of a cell array is longer than a certain length (appears to be 19 characters for strings), matlab doesn't print the actual element, it prints a description of the content instead (in this case,  "[1x23 char]").

For example:

```
>> names = {'1234567890123456789' 'bar' 'car'}
names = 
    '1234567890123456789'    'bar'    'car'
>> names = {'12345678901234567890' 'bar' 'car'}
names = 
    [1x20 char]    'bar'    'car'
```

`celldisp` might work better for your situation:

```
>> celldisp(names)
names{1} =
12345678901234567890
names{2} =
bar
names{3} =
car
```